# Haskell sudoku solver

Tags: haskell, sudoku

I'm a beginner in functional programming and I'm making a sudoku solver in Haskell.
Sudokus are contained as `[(posX,posY),value)]`, if a position is blank, it is not in the list.

Currently I have a function, `step :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]`. If the sudoku is already solved, it returns a single element list containing that sudoku. If it is not already solved, but can be, it checks for the first blank position that can be clearly written in (so with only one correct number), and adds it to the sudoku. If there is no such blank point (so multiple numbers fit), it gets the first blank point and makes a list containing multiple sudokus with all the different, valid variations of that point. Lastly, if the sudoku cannot be solved, it returns an empty list.

I know it is exhausting but this is how I was assigned to do it, so please bear with me. My next thing to do is to write an actual solving function, using `step` (which really is just a single step in solving it), and it has to be like this: `solve :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]`. It gets a sudoku, and returns all the possible solutions in a list.

The problem is that I have no idea how. It is probably a recursion using black magic, and I cannot get my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's the full source code, I figured out the last function too, but currently it is very slow. Is there any way to make is faster?

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
type Cell = (Pos, Int)
type Sudoku = [Cell]
type Block = Int

--example:
sudoku :: Sudoku
sudoku = [((0,0),3),((0,1),6),((0,4),7),((0,5),1),((0,6),2),
          ((1,1),5),((1,6),1),((1,7),8),
          ((2,2),9),((2,3),2),((2,5),4),((2,6),7),
          ((3,4),1),((3,5),3),((3,7),2),((3,8),8),
          ((4,0),4),((4,3),5),((4,5),2),((4,8),9),
          ((5,0),2),((5,1),7),((5,3),4),((5,4),6),
          ((6,2),5),((6,3),3),((6,5),8),((6,6),9),
          ((7,1),8),((7,2),3),((7,7),6),
          ((8,2),7),((8,3),6),((8,4),9),((8,7),4),((8,8),3)]

--returns a list of numbers already used in a row
numsInRow :: Sudoku -> Int -> [Int]
numsInRow sud n = [ i | ((x,y), i) <- sud, x==n ]

--returns a list of numbers already used in a column
numsInCol :: Sudoku -> Int -> [Int]
numsInCol sud n = [ i | ((x,y), i) <- sud, y==n ]

--returns the index of a block (goes from 0 to 8) in which the given position is contained
posToBlock :: Pos -> Block
posToBlock (x,y) = x - (x `mod` 3) + y `div` 3

--returns all the positions in a block
blockToPositions :: Block -> [Pos]
blockToPositions n
   | n `notElem` [0..8] = error ("blockToPositions: bad block number " ++ show n)
   | otherwise = [ (x,y) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8], n == (x - (x `mod` 3) + y `div` 3) ]

--returns the numbers already used in a block
numsInBlock :: Sudoku -> Block -> [Int]
numsInBlock sud n = [ i | ((x,y), i) <- sud, (j,k) <- blockToPositions n, (x,y) == (j,k)]

--decides if all the elements are unique in a list
allUnique :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allUnique [] = True
allUnique (x:xs) 
  | x `elem` xs = False
  | otherwise = allUnique xs

--returns if a sudoku is valid, so it is 9x9, all the values are between 1 and 9, and there are no repeating numbers in any row, column, or block
isSudokuPuzzle :: Sudoku -> Bool
isSudokuPuzzle sud = and [and [ x `elem` [0..8] && y `elem` [0..8] && z `elem` [1..9] | ((x,y), z) <- sud ] , and [ allUnique a | a <- [numsInRow sud i | i <- [0..8] ]] , and [ allUnique a | a <- [numsInCol sud i | i <- [0..8] ]] , and [ allUnique a | a <- [numsInBlock sud i | i <- [0..8] ]]]

--returns if a sudoku is filled, so all the fields have values (and only one value)
isFilled :: Sudoku -> Bool
isFilled sud = allUnique [ (x,y) | ((x,y), z) <- sud ] && length [ (x,y) | ((x,y), z) <- sud ] == 81

--a sudoku is solved if it is a valid sudoku and filled
isSolved :: Sudoku -> Bool
isSolved sud = isSudokuPuzzle sud && isFilled sud

--decides if a position is blank (has no value, not filled) in a sudoku
isBlank :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Bool
isBlank sud (x,y) = (x,y) `notElem` [ (j,k) | ((j,k),l) <- sud ]

--gives back a list of all empty positions in a sudoku
blankPositions :: Sudoku -> [Pos]
blankPositions sud = [ (x,y) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8], isBlank sud (x,y) ]

--returns a list of all valid numbers in a position (empty if position is already filled)
possibleNumsOnPos :: Sudoku -> Pos -> [Int]
possibleNumsOnPos sud (x,y)  
   | isBlank sud (x,y) = [ i | i <- [1..9], i `notElem` numsInRow sud x, i `notElem` numsInCol sud y, i `notElem` numsInBlock sud (posToBlock (x,y)) ]
   | otherwise = []

--returns a list of all the blank positions and their possible values in a sudoku
possibleNumsForBlankPos :: Sudoku -> [(Pos, [Int])]
possibleNumsForBlankPos sud = [ ((x,y), possibleNumsOnPos sud (x,y)) | x <- [0..8], y <- [0..8], isBlank sud (x,y)]

--dedices if a sudoku has a solution (so there is still at least one blank and it has at least one valid value)
hasSolution :: [(Pos, [Int])] -> Bool
hasSolution [] = False
hasSolution a = and [ not (null l) | ((j,k),l) <- a ]

--returns a list of blanks that have only one possible valid value
uniqueNumForBlankPos :: [(Pos, [Int])] -> [(Pos, Int)]
uniqueNumForBlankPos a = [ ((j,k),head l) | ((j,k),l) <- a, length l == 1 ]

--fills a field in a sudoku with a given value
insertElem :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Int -> Sudoku
insertElem sud (x,y) n 
   | isBlank sud (x,y) = ((x,y),n):sud
   | otherwise = error ("insertElem: position " ++ show (x,y) ++ " is not blank")


--If the sudoku is already solved, it returns a single element list containing that sudoku.
--If it is not already solved, but can be, it checks for the first blank position that has only one possible valid value, and adds it to the sudoku.
--If there is no such blank point (so all blanks have multiple valid values), it gets the first blank point and makes a list containing multiple sudokus with all the different, valid variations of that point.
--Lastly, if the sudoku cannot be solved, it returns an empty list.
step :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]
step sud
   | isSolved sud = [sud]
   | hasSolution (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud) && not (null (uniqueNumForBlankPos (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud))) = [ insertElem sud (fst (head (uniqueNumForBlankPos (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud)))) (snd (head (uniqueNumForBlankPos (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud)))) ]
   | hasSolution (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud) && null (uniqueNumForBlankPos (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud)) = [ insertElem sud (head (blankPositions sud)) x | x <- possibleNumsOnPos sud (head (blankPositions sud)) ]
   | not (hasSolution (possibleNumsForBlankPos sud)) = []

--It gets a sudoku, and returns all the possible solutions in a list, but currently it is very slow.
solve :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]
solve sud 
    | not (isSudokuPuzzle sud) = error "solve: improper sudoku"
    | otherwise = 
     until done f l 
       where 
         l = return sud
         f (x:xs) = (f xs) ++ step x 
         f [] = []
         done m = and (map isSolved m ) && and (map isSudokuPuzzle m)
```

Comment: it's not black magic - one way is to use the `do` notation for the list-monad (it will make all the combinations for you) - sadly it's impossible to help you out more because there is not a single line of code here and honestly: I don't want to write down the complete solver for you

Comment: if you want to cheat you can have a look at the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Sudoku) or this [paper](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/richard-bird/sudoku.pdf) most likely your exercise is build on the paper

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into steps:

1. How can you tell if a partial solution is a finished solution? Simple: since a `Sudoku` is a list of filled positions, a finished solution is a list with 81 elements. (Assuming a standard 9x9 Sudoku puzzle).

   Task: write `isFinished :: Sudoku -> Bool`
2. Given a list of solutions, how do you know when you are done? Easy: every solution on the list is a finished solution. You could test that directly, or check if `x == (step x)`.

   Task: write `partials :: [Sudoku] -> [Sudoku]`, which removes finished solutions from its input.
3. To process a list of solutions, you need to apply `step` to each one and collect the results. This is precisely the type of computation that the list monad is ideal for: `partial_solutions >>= step`.
4. To implement `solve :: Sudoku -> [Sudoku]`, it helps to write `solve' :: [Sudoku] -> [Sudoku]`, where `solve initState = solve' [initState]`. `solve'` itself is a fairly straightforward recursive function if you keep 1-3 above in mind.

Comment: Or as an alternative:  1. Write `isFinished`  2. `import Data.SBV`  3. `sat isFinished`.